# Change of basis and independence problem

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

[image]

I'm asking about b), what does "independent of the choice of the matrix" mean exactly? What do we need to show? Can somebody give a hint please...

Comment: If you change the basis $\{v_1,v_2\}$ to some other basis $\{w_1,w_2\}$, then the matrix for $T$ will change, because matrices are always expressed relative to bases. But the question is asking you to prove that $T(w_1 + 2w_2)$ does not change if you change the basis to $\{w_1,w_2\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A = \begin{bmatrix} 3&5\\1&2 \end{bmatrix}$ will take vector $x_{a'}$ (in terms of the basis $a'$) to is corresponding vector in term of the basis $a.$

and $A^{-1}$ will take a vector in terms of the basis $a$ to its eqivalent in basis $a'.$

$A^{-1}TA\mathbf x_{a'}$ will take a vector in the basis $a'$ take it to the basis $a$ transform it in the basis $a$ and take the result back to the basis $a'$